# What's the right way to insert a CalibratedClassifierCV in a scikit-learn pipeline?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to add a calibration step in a sklearn pipeline to obtain a calibrated classifier and thus [have more trustworthy probabilities](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) in output.

So far I clumsily tried to insert a 'calibration' step using [CalibratedClassifierCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html#sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV) along the lines of (silly example for reproducibility):

```
import sklearn.datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

data = sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(categories=['alt.atheism', 'sci.space'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.c_[data['data'], data['target']])\
       .rename({0:'text', 1:'class'}, axis = 'columns')

my_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('classifier', SGDClassifier(loss='modified_huber')),
    ('calibrator', CalibratedClassifierCV(cv=5, method='isotonic'))
])

my_pipeline.fit(df['text'].values, df['class'].values)
```

but that doesn't work (at least not in this way). Does anyone have tips about how to properly do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `SGDClassifier` object should go into the [`CalibratedClassifierCV`'s `base_estimator` argument](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html#sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV).

Your code should probably look something like this:

```
my_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('classifier', CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=SGDClassifier(loss='modified_huber'), cv=5, method='isotonic'))
])
```

`CalibratedClassifierCV` is a meta-estimator.

Comment: Is it possible to add gridsearchcv above this pipeline to search hyerparamters of CalibratedClassifierCV's base_estimator? I can not figure out the correct format of params_grid. wish your help.

Comment: @Feiyang.Chen I am wondering about the same thing, did you manage to find a solution yet? An easy solution is to use a `GridSearchCV` step first, find the `best_estimator_`, and then use it in `CalibratedClassifierCV` with `cv='prefit'`.

Comment: Yes, it's possible via **classifier__base_estimator__loss: ['hinge','modified_huber']** for example, where *classifier* is name of your calibration step in the pipeline, and *loss* is name of your base estimator parameter which you want to grid search.